# gitweb became slow

Tags: git, gitweb

I have pointed $projectroot to directory which is of 400GB contains n number of git projects. earlier we had only few project and gitweb started very fast, once project number started growing it is taking time to load. IS there any way to speed up ?

Answer (score 4):

Gitweb recursively searches all directories under `$projectroot` to find projects. If there are lots of files displaying the top level will take lots of time. Try adding

> $project_maxdepth = 1; # or slightly larger integer depending your project layout

in your /etc/gitweb.conf to limit the searches to first directory levels of `$projectroot`.

Like andygavin's answer suggests it's easy to get huge directory trees under `$projectroot` if you have non-bare repositories that contain also the checkouts there. It's better to have the checkouts somewhere else and only bare repositories under gitweb. Use

> git clone --bare /path/to/projects/project /path/to/gitweb/project

to make bare clone for gitweb from your non-bare project and then configure `$projectroot` to `/path/to/gitweb/` instead of `/path/to/projects/`.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell why it is slow however the repository has a lot of loose objects try:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

It is good practice that the gitweb repository is *bare*, I'm not clear size that you mention whether you have the files alongside the index.